# Serialization: Passing Object as URL Parameter and extracting values

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, url-parameters

I want to pass Object through URL Parameter by converting it to string by Serialization it and then get the Object back by Deserialization.

Here is what I have done:

During the URL Parameters creation:

```
SerializationUtils.getAsString(localMarketHomeDTO.getPointInTime()); //serializing it
```

During the extraction of the values:

```
SerializationUtils.getAsObject(paramValue.toString(),Class.forName("java.util.Date")); //deserializing it
```

Here `localMarketHomeDTO.getPointInTime()` is of the type `java.util.Date`.

The class `SerializationUtils` is:

```
public class SerializationUtils{

    private SerializationUtils(){

    }

    public static <T extends Serializable> String getAsString(T object) throws Exception {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(object);
        objectOutputStream.flush();
        return byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
    }

    public static <T> T getAsObject(String string, Class<T> clazz) throws Exception {
        byte[] byteArray = string.getBytes("UTF-8");
        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(byteArrayInputStream);
        T object = clazz.cast(objectInputStream.readObject());
        return object;
    }
}
```

But I am having exception:

```
'java.util.Date; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 7523895402267505689, local class serialVersionUID = 7523967970034938905' due to 'java.io.InvalidClassException: java.util.Date; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 7523895402267505689, local class serialVersionUID = 7523967970034938905'
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Use base64 to convert array of bytes to String:
java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byte[] src)
java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(String src)

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 decoding does not map all sequences of bytes onto characters, so you are going to lose data. Your URL parameters may not be able to cope with all characters either.

In any case, you appear to be allowing the serialised data to be doctored, which is a really bad idea for a number of reasons.

Comment: Without the UTF-8? As in whatever default character set happens to be in operation? Not likely to be much better. You'd need to encode it with Base64 or similar.